# CSS webkit-animation scroll top

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-transitions

I'm not very good in CSS.

Following CSS continuously scroll the background image.

But I need to do is scroll top and stop the animation of the background image. Could you please help me on this matter.

```
body {
     background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/img /sas-sport-bg.jpg'; ?>);

    -webkit-animation:400s scroll  linear;
    -moz-animation:400s scroll  linear;
    -o-animation:400s scroll  linear;
    -ms-animation:400s scroll  linear;
    animation:400s scroll  linear;
}
 @-webkit-keyframes scroll{
    0%{
        background-position:0px 0px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes scroll{
    20%{
        background-position:0px -1000px;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes scroll{
    40%{
        background-position:0px -1000px;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes scroll{
    80%{
        background-position:0px -1000px;
    }
}
@keyframes scroll{
    100%{
        background-position:0px -1000px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `animation-fill-mode` to `forwards` in your animation to stop the animation at the last state.

check the code below:

```
body {
         background-image: url(<?php echo get_template_directory_uri().'/img /sas-sport-bg.jpg'; ?>);

        -webkit-animation:400s scroll  linear forwards;
        -moz-animation:400s scroll  linear forwards;
        -o-animation:400s scroll  linear forwards;
        -ms-animation:400s scroll  linear forwards;
        animation:400s scroll  linear forwards;
    }
     @-webkit-keyframes scroll{
        100%{
            background-position:0px -1000px;
        }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes scroll{
        100%{
            background-position:0px -1000px;
        }
    }
    @-o-keyframes scroll{
        100%{
            background-position:0px -1000px;
        }
    }
    @-ms-keyframes scroll{
        100%{
            background-position:0px -1000px;
        }
    }
    @keyframes scroll{
        100%{
            background-position:0px -1000px;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Amr Labib .  This is not what I expected. Background should Scroll to top and should stop. Like https://www.pinterest.com/ login page.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question ... i just checked pinterest animation ... so basically you need to stop the background image animation when it reach the end ..... i updated the answer to do the same effect ... you just need to use ```forwards``` in your animation ....